# c++ overload constructor with int and char*

Tags: c++, constructor, overloading, ambiguity

I try to overload constructor with `int` and `char *`. Then there is ambiguity in call with `0`. Is there any workaround/solution for this?

```
CBigInt (unsigned int);
CBigInt (const char *);
```

The problem is on the line with `0`:

```
CBigInt a;
// some more code
 a *= 0;
```

Thanks for answering.

Comment: I assume you have overloaded `operator *=`? It had me confused for a moment.

Comment: If you use `std::string`, it won't happen.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make one of the constructors explicit. It will then only be used when passed type exactly matches.

```
CBigInt (unsigned int);
explicit CBigInt (const char *);
```

Comment: even better, make both explicit :)

Comment: @Matthieu M: Nah, then he'd have to write `a *= CBigInt(0u)`, given the usage scenario OP showed I'd think by default he want integrals to convert to `CBigInt`

Comment: yes, this works, but I forgot to say, that I want be able to write conversions from chars * as well, like : `a *= "131"`

Comment: You could make op *= like this (in addition to the one taking Foo) `template<typename T> CBigInt & operator*=(T const & V) { return *this *= CBigInt(V); }` - that should work OK together with a few explicit constructors.

Answer (score 6):

You could use the "explicit" keyword:

```
explicit CBigInt(const char *);
```

Using this, you must explicitly cast the argument to a const char *, otherwise CBigInt(unsigned) will be executed.

Answer (score 2):

The 'explicit' approach works, but may not be intuitive for supporting developers in the future.
For cases like these, in previous projects I've worked on, we used static factory methods.
We would have a private default constructor and explicitly initialize the members in the static factories. Something like:

```
class CBigInt {
public:
...
static CBigInt fromUInt(unsigned int i) { 
    CBigInt result; 
    result.value=i; 
    return result; 
}
static CBigInt fromCharPtr(const char* c) { 
    CBigInt result; 
    result.value=parse(c); 
    return result; 
}
...
private:
CBigInt () {}
/*some internal type here*/ value; 
};
```

This approach removes any ambiguity not only for the compiler, but also for the one who will support your code later.

Answer (score 1):

In this case I would also recommend an `explicit` constructor, because I think that an arbitrary string (which your constructor takes) does not model a number (which your `CBigInt` class models). Such cases are what `explicit` was designed for.

However, this will not work for cases where direct initialization is used

```
struct A {
  CBigInt n;
  A():n(0) { } // ambiguity again
};
```

In general, `explicit` should not be used to resolve internal ambiguities. It should merely be used to forbid the conversion from one type to the other, but not to prefer another constructor over the `explicit` constructor. In fact, the new C++0x uniform initializations will *not* ignore `explicit` constructors in a copy initialization context:

```
CBigInt f() {
  return { 0 }; // still ambiguous
}

CBigInt b = { 0 }; // still ambiguous
```

The rules for uniform initialization is: Both constructors are considered, but if an explicit constructor is chosen, initialization is ill-formed.

The literal `0` is an `int`. Assuming you want to be able to accept all integer types, you need to at least add an `int` taking constructor. You don't need to add overloads for integer types smaller than `int`, because those types prefer `int` over other integer conversions or pointers. Assuming you have an `int` overload you also need to add overloads for the remaining integer types and, if available and you use it, `long long` and `unsigned long long`. Ambiguities will then not arise anymore:

```
CBigInt (int);
CBigInt (unsigned int);
CBigInt (long);
CBigInt (unsigned long);
// CBigInt (long long);
// CBigInt (unsigned long long);
explicit CBigInt (const char *);
```

Comment: To clarify: adding `CBigInt::CBigInt(int)` get rid of ambiguity in the OP's sample.